# How to pass user product details from node.js application to paypal?

Tags: node.js, paypal

I have a button in my node.js application to buy the product whatever user wants. I want to know how to pass that product details (amount etc) to paypal so that user can pay me via paypal. Is there any in-built library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use `paypal-rest-sdk` module.

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs

Here's a sample code taken from [here](http://runnable.com/UXgzNO_v2oZyAADG/make-a-payment-with-paypal-api-for-node-js).

```
var paypal_api = require('paypal-rest-sdk');

var config_opts = {
    'host': 'api.sandbox.paypal.com',
    'port': '',
    'client_id': 'EBWKjlELKMYqRNQ6sYvFo64FtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM',
    'client_secret': 'EO422dn3gQLgDbuwqTjzrFgFtaRLRR5BdHEESmha49TM'
};


var create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http:\/\/localhost\/test\/rest\/rest-api-sdk-php\/sample\/payments\/ExecutePayment.php?success=true",
        "cancel_url": "http:\/\/localhost\/test\/rest\/rest-api-sdk-php\/sample\/payments\/ExecutePayment.php?success=false"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": "1.00"
        },
        "description": "This is the payment description."
    }]
};


paypal_api.payment.create(create_payment_json, config_opts, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    if (res) {
        console.log("Create Payment Response");
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Comment: its successfully redirected to paypal but i only got description field on paypal not amount field..?